# Xamarin - Can't build App when referencing Objective-C Binding

Tags: objective-c, xamarin.ios, xamarin

Here is my build error (with `-v -v -v` on):

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++  -ObjC -lsqlite3 -lc++ -Wl,-pie  -miphoneos-version-min=5.0 -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk  /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/MyApp.exe.armv7.o /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/Blendgine.XNA.dll.armv7.o /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/mscorlib.dll.armv7.o /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/MonoGame.Framework.dll.armv7.o /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/OpenTK.dll.armv7.o /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/monotouch.dll.armv7.o /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/System.dll.armv7.o /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/System.Core.dll.armv7.o /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/System.Xml.dll.armv7.o /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.armv7.o /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/Blendgine.Core.dll.armv7.o /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/MonoTouch.FacebookConnect.dll.armv7.o /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll.armv7.o /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/System.Xml.Linq.dll.armv7.o /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/GoogleAnalytics.dll.armv7.o /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Messaging.dll.armv7.o /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/MonoTouch.Dialog-1.dll.armv7.o /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/System.Json.dll.armv7.o /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/Newtonsoft.Json.dll.armv7.o /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/Blendgine.GooglePlay.dll.armv7.o /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/PlayGameServices.dll.armv7.o /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/Blendgine.Tapjoy.dll.armv7.o /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/Tapjoy.dll.armv7.o /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/registrar.armv7.o /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/main.armv7.o -force_load /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/libFacebookSDK.a -force_load /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/libarclite.a -force_load /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/libGoogleAnalytics.a -force_load /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/WindowsAzureMessaging.a -force_load /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/PlayGameServices.a -force_load /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/GooglePlus.a -force_load /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/GoogleOpenSource.a -force_load /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/TapjoyPublisherLibrary.a -o /MyPath/bin/iPhone/Debug/MyAppiOS.app/MyApp -framework CFNetwork -framework AVFoundation -framework Accelerate -framework AddressBook -framework AudioToolbox -framework QuartzCore -framework CoreBluetooth -framework CoreData -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreImage -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreText -framework Foundation -framework GameKit -framework ImageIO -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreMIDI -framework CoreVideo -framework StoreKit -framework AssetsLibrary -framework CoreTelephony -framework EventKit -framework EventKitUI -framework CoreMotion -framework GLKit -framework iAd -framework MapKit -framework MediaPlayer -framework MessageUI -framework NewsstandKit -framework OpenGLES -framework Twitter -framework UIKit -framework AddressBookUI -framework ExternalAccessory -framework QuickLook -weak_framework Social -weak_framework PassKit -weak_framework SpriteKit -weak_framework JavaScriptCore -weak_framework MultipeerConnectivity -weak_framework GameController -weak_framework MediaAccessibility -weak_framework SafariServices -weak_framework AdSupport -weak_framework Accounts -lz -liconv -u _mono_pmip -u _xamarin_init_nsthread -u _xamarin_get_block_descriptor -u _monotouch_get_locale_country_code -u _monotouch_log -u _monotouch_start_wwan -u _monotouch_timezone_get_data -u _monotouch_timezone_get_names -u _monotouch_IntPtr_objc_msgSend_IntPtr -u _monotouch_IntPtr_objc_msgSendSuper_IntPtr -u _monotouch_release_managed_ref -u _monotouch_create_managed_ref -u _CloseZStream -u _CreateZStream -u _Flush -u _ReadZStream -u _WriteZStream /Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.a /Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/lib/libmonotouch-sgen-debug.a
Process exited with code 1, command:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++  -ObjC -lsqlite3 -lc++ -Wl,-pie  -miphoneos-version-min=5.0 -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk  /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/MyApp.exe.armv7.o /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/Blendgine.XNA.dll.armv7.o /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/mscorlib.dll.armv7.o /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/MonoGame.Framework.dll.armv7.o /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/OpenTK.dll.armv7.o /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/monotouch.dll.armv7.o /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/System.dll.armv7.o /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/System.Core.dll.armv7.o /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/System.Xml.dll.armv7.o /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.armv7.o /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/Blendgine.Core.dll.armv7.o /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/MonoTouch.FacebookConnect.dll.armv7.o /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll.armv7.o /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/System.Xml.Linq.dll.armv7.o /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/GoogleAnalytics.dll.armv7.o /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Messaging.dll.armv7.o /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/MonoTouch.Dialog-1.dll.armv7.o /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/System.Json.dll.armv7.o /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/Newtonsoft.Json.dll.armv7.o /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/Blendgine.GooglePlay.dll.armv7.o /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/PlayGameServices.dll.armv7.o /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/Blendgine.Tapjoy.dll.armv7.o /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/Tapjoy.dll.armv7.o /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/registrar.armv7.o /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/main.armv7.o -force_load /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/libFacebookSDK.a -force_load /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/libarclite.a -force_load /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/libGoogleAnalytics.a -force_load /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/WindowsAzureMessaging.a -force_load /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/PlayGameServices.a -force_load /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/GooglePlus.a -force_load /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/GoogleOpenSource.a -force_load /MyPath/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/TapjoyPublisherLibrary.a -o /MyPath/bin/iPhone/Debug/MyAppiOS.app/MyApp -framework CFNetwork -framework AVFoundation -framework Accelerate -framework AddressBook -framework AudioToolbox -framework QuartzCore -framework CoreBluetooth -framework CoreData -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreImage -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreText -framework Foundation -framework GameKit -framework ImageIO -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreMIDI -framework CoreVideo -framework StoreKit -framework AssetsLibrary -framework CoreTelephony -framework EventKit -framework EventKitUI -framework CoreMotion -framework GLKit -framework iAd -framework MapKit -framework MediaPlayer -framework MessageUI -framework NewsstandKit -framework OpenGLES -framework Twitter -framework UIKit -framework AddressBookUI -framework ExternalAccessory -framework QuickLook -weak_framework Social -weak_framework PassKit -weak_framework SpriteKit -weak_framework JavaScriptCore -weak_framework MultipeerConnectivity -weak_framework GameController -weak_framework MediaAccessibility -weak_framework SafariServices -weak_framework AdSupport -weak_framework Accounts -lz -liconv -u _mono_pmip -u _xamarin_init_nsthread -u _xamarin_get_block_descriptor -u _monotouch_get_locale_country_code -u _monotouch_log -u _monotouch_start_wwan -u _monotouch_timezone_get_data -u _monotouch_timezone_get_names -u _monotouch_IntPtr_objc_msgSend_IntPtr -u _monotouch_IntPtr_objc_msgSendSuper_IntPtr -u _monotouch_release_managed_ref -u _monotouch_create_managed_ref -u _CloseZStream -u _CreateZStream -u _Flush -u _ReadZStream -u _WriteZStream /Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.a /Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/lib/libmonotouch-sgen-debug.a
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_EVP_add_alg_module", referenced from:
      _OPENSSL_load_builtin_modules in PlayGameServices.a(conf_mall.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _EVP_add_alg_module. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
error MT5202: Native linking failed. Please review the build log.
```

So my binding project has three *.a libraries added. Here is a sample of the `LinkWith` attribute I have setup (I did the same for all three, but with different .a file, of course):

```
[assembly: LinkWith ("PlayGameServices.a", LinkTarget.ArmV7 | LinkTarget.ArmV7s | LinkTarget.Simulator, 
    Frameworks = "AddressBook AssetsLibrary CoreData CoreGraphics CoreLocation CoreMotion CoreText Foundation MediaPlayer QuartzCore Security SystemConfiguration UIKit", LinkerFlags = "-lc++", IsCxx = true,
    ForceLoad = true)]
```

Here is a screenshot of the library's sample Xcode project, with its list of frameworks:

[image: frameworks]

I'm sure XCTest isn't needed. What am I missing?

Comment: That sounds like it's the **app** (not the **binding**) that cannot be built (even if the issue is likely the binding).

Comment: When I searched online, it sounded like that symbol was inside OpenSSL and it should be in the Security framework. If I remove the reference to the binding, the app builds fine. Any ideas on something to try?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In part because it does not offer binary API compatibility your code (or libraries) cannot bind to the iOS installed version of **openssl** (i.e. it's a private library).

It's common for some libraries to include their own copy of openssl.

From the above my *guess* is that `ForceLoad` is loading everything (as asked) but the static library (PlayGameServices.a) might be missing some symbols. Such error might not be reported if everything was not loaded (i.e. no ForceLoad). To test this you can try the ObjC with forceload.

You might also want to try using `SmartLink = true` and set `ForceLoad = false`. That should reduce your application size and, as it won't be loading every symbols, might work around the issue in the static library (missing symbol).

Comment: OTOH it looks like you are already aware of `SmartLink` - http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/5279/ios-smart-link-native-libraries

Comment: Turning on `SmartLink` and turning off `ForceLoad` gives me a new error: `error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_main'.` inside PlayGameServices.a.

Comment: This library is a pile of poop.

Comment: If I put this project in a private repo on Github, would you take a look? Or would you rather me submit a private bug? (but I don't think it's a Xamarin bug) I can also send a support request, we've got Enterprise Priority license.

Comment: Open a (private) bug report. The component store ships a version (it might not be the same) so we have people with some experience with the library (and if you're using a newer version then the test case might prove useful).

Comment: Ok, I created a repro and it worked. Found out that a Facebook binding in combination is creating the issue... I'll still send it, but will take me a sec to find you the FB binding.

Comment: ah, that makes *kind of* sense (as to why it worked for the component store).

Comment: It's a new "private" beta of the library. Posted a bug here: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=17451

Comment: Ok, after we went through the bug report: set ForceLoad to false, and SmartLink to true in the binding definition. Add `--gcc_flags dead_strip` to the iOS build parameters in the app project. Marking @poupou as the answer, though.